# Getting wrong colors after an image manipulations

Tags: c#, colors, bitmap, xor

I am trying to XOR some values with RGB values of my image, save that image and to do  back steps, to get an original image.
The problem is, that I don't know why I get not clear (with some noise) image.
Here is my code, and an image below:

```
Bitmap original = new Bitmap("D:\\img\\1.jpg");
Bitmap inp_bmp = new Bitmap("D:\\img\\1.jpg");

int width = inp_bmp.Width;
int height = inp_bmp.Height;
Color pixel;

for (int y = 0; y < height; y += 1)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 1)
    {
        pixel = inp_bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

        int a = pixel.A;
        int r = (pixel.R ^ (1000))%256;
        int g = (pixel.G ^ (185675))%256;
        int b = (pixel.B ^ (78942))%256;
        inp_bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b));


    }
}

pictureBox2.Image = inp_bmp;
pictureBox1.Image = original;
inp_bmp.Save("D:\\img\\4.jpg");
```

After an image has been saved, I change

```
Bitmap inp_bmp = new Bitmap("D:\\img\\1.jpg");
```

for

```
 Bitmap inp_bmp = new Bitmap("D:\\img\\4.jpg");
```

and remove

```
//inp_bmp.Save("D:\\img\\4.jpg");
```

and I get an image like

[image]

(left original, right - result);
As you can see, I get some wrong colors at picture 4, why?
All in all it is close to original, but still it's not right

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Your code works fine here with real jpegs. Can you post the original image?

Comment: Here it is Sir - http://i62.tinypic.com/20jqrea.jpg

Comment: Sorry my friend, there is nothing wrong with the posted code. The result here looks exactly the same as the original. However __both__ your 1st changed and the 2nd one look as if they have a reduced palette, like an undithered gif would have. There must be something else going on!

Comment: `& 0xFF` is probably loads more efficient than `% 256`, since it's a bit operation rather than a division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, I found the problem. The problem was with saving an image.

This helped:

```
 inp_bmp.Save("D:\\img\\4.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your image does not use 8 bit colors. `% 256` assumes you have an 8-bit image.

Comment: tried with out % 256 like int r = (pixel.R ^ 220);
                    int g = (pixel.G ^ 255);
                    int b = (pixel.B ^ 206); still same problem

Comment: jpeg always has 8-bit colour components. In fact, all web images do as far as I know.